# \setstretch command does not work

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, setspace

In the following example when I typeset, `\setstretch` does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}‎

\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ‎
{\setstretch{5.0}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ‎
}‎
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You must terminate the paragraph before the closing brace. `{\setstretch{1.5}bla...bla\par}`

Comment: Along these lines, I would recommend using the `spacing` environment rather then using `\setstretch` directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't work inside a group without `\par`. Use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ‎

\setstretch{5.0}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ‎

\setstretch{1.0}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

or

```
... empty line
{\setstretch{5.0}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ‎
\par}
```