# Minipage in a movie credit: can't find how to have constant space around them (both vertically and horizontally)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, vertical-spacing

My goal is to create in LaTeX a Credit like:

[image]

However, I have two problems of alignement:

- First, the items are not aligned horizontally: see for example that Eve is on the right compared to Dan
- Secondly, the items are not equally spaced vertically (I want a small space inside lines of a same entry, and a larger space between entries). See for example here that the distance Dan-Eve is much smaller than the distance Eve-Fabrice.

What's wrong with my code?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, crop, varwidth]{standalone}
% Convert to png with:
% convert -density 4000 models.pdf -format png -colorspace rgb models.png
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\newcommand{\addCreditEntry}[2]{%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{.40\linewidth}\raggedleft
        {\setstretch{0.5}
          #1\par}%
      \end{minipage}\hspace{5mm}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{.40\linewidth}\raggedright
        {\setstretch{0.5}
          #2\par}%
      \end{minipage}
    \end{center}%
  \end{minipage}\\
  \vspace{1mm}
} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176983/setstretch-command-does-not-work

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\Large
  My Movie
\end{center}

\addCreditEntry{Film Maker}{Alice}%
\addCreditEntry{Studio manager}{Bob}%
\addCreditEntry{Costume Designers}{Charlie\\
  Dan}
\addCreditEntry{Tripod Loan}{Eve}%
\addCreditEntry{Drum player}{Fabrice}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you do that with a `tabular`?

Comment: You can adjust the vertical spacing inside a tabular with, for example, `\def\arraystretch{2.0}`.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, tabular was good enough. At the beginning I wanted to avoid them in order to get a nice syntax like `\addCreditEntry{Film Maker}{Alice}`, and finally I kept using this syntax and just created one tabular per entry. But I'm still curious to know if there is a move fundamental block than `minipage` on which I can explicitely fix the space before, after... For example, how is implemented `tabular`?